# nginx-prometheus-exporter deployment failing

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I am trying to deploy `Nginx` with `nginx-prometheus-exporter`. Following is my deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: local
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - name: nginx-port
          containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: nginx-port
            httpHeaders:
              - name: Host
                value: KubernetesLivenessProbe
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 15
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: nginx-port
            httpHeaders:
              - name: Host
                value: KubernetesLivenessProbe
          initialDelaySeconds: 3
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 8
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/ # mount nginx-conf volume to /etc/nginx
          readOnly: true
          name: frontend-conf
      - name: nginx-exporter
        image: nginx/nginx-prometheus-exporter:0.3.0
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - name: nginx-ex-port
          containerPort: 9113
        args:
          - -nginx.scrape-uri=http://nginx.local.svc.cluster.local:80/stub_status
      volumes:
      - name: frontend-conf
        configMap:
          name: frontend-conf # place ConfigMap `nginx-conf` on /etc/nginx
          items:
            - key: frontend.local.conf
              path: frontend.local.conf
```

Single container pod works, but fails when I add `nginx-prometheus-exporter` sidecar container.

```
mackbook: xyz$ kubectl logs nginx-6dbbdb64fb-8drmc -c nginx-exporter
2019/05/14 20:17:48 Starting NGINX Prometheus Exporter Version=0.3.0 GitCommit=6570275
2019/05/14 20:17:53 Could not create Nginx Client: Failed to create NginxClient: failed to get http://nginx.local.svc.cluster.local:80/stub_status: Get http://nginx.local.svc.cluster.local:80/stub_status: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Also was able to `curl http://nginx.local.svc.cluster.local` from another container running in different namespace.

Anyone know what's the correct way to specify  `-nginx.scrape-uri` ?

From Nginx container

```
root@nginx-6fd866c4d7-t8wwf:/# curl localhost/stub_status
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<h1>404 Not Found</h1>
<ul>
<li>Code: NoSuchKey</li>
<li>Message: The specified key does not exist.</li>
<li>Key: beta/stub_status</li>
<li>RequestId: 3319E5A424C7BA31</li>
<li>HostId: zVv5zuAyzqbB2Gw3w1DavEJwgq2sbgI8RPMf7RmPsNQoh/9ftxCmiSwyj/j6q/K3lxEEeUy6aZM=</li>
</ul>
<hr/>
</body>
</html>
root@nginx-6fd866c4d7-t8wwf:/#
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fails" ? Can you show us the sidecar logs ?

Comment: added logs form sidecar container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx container is listening on port 80, and you configure the sidecar to access to 8080 port. Moreover, you deploy this in "production" namespace, but using "test" to access to nginx.

Try with `-nginx.scrape-uri=http://nginx.production.svc.cluster.local:80/stub_status`.

BTW you must know that containers within a Pod share an IP address and port space, and can find each other via localhost.

So you can use `-nginx.scrape-uri=http://localhost/stub_status`.

Comment: Still not working with localhost ? In this case, does the sidecar logs changes ? Can you get into the nginx container with bash and do a curl on `localhost/stub_status` ? What is the result of the curl ?

Comment: So I think with localhost the sidecar can now reach the nginx container (you can try by getting into the sidecar container and doing a curl on localhost/stub_status - you should have a 404 too). Here the point is that nginx is not exposing stub_status. Can you show us the content of `frontend.local.conf` ?

Comment: Totally forgot to add `location /stub_status {stub_status;}` in nginx config.

Comment: What target I need to use in static_configs `- targets: ['nginx.local.svc.cluster.local:80']` ?

Comment: Use the sidecar port ie 9113

Comment: I tried `targets: ['nginx.local.svc.cluster.local:9113']` and got `Get http://nginx.local.svc.cluster.local:9113/stub_status: context deadline exceeded`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193410/discussion-between-roy-and-alexandre-cartapanis).